# Controller connects and the screen keeps panning up constantly

Tags: controllers, ps4

Guys for some reason whenever I connect my controller and put on a game, for some reason, the camera pans upward, as if I was moving the camera with the right analog stick.

I tried resetting it, but it didn't work. I also tried a reboot to default settings, but the camera still pans up. I'd put it down and the screen would slowly pan back up. The analog feels fine, but is it that or something else?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling your controllers drivers?

Comment: @SamJ If it's on the PS4, there isn't really a way to reset drivers. It's more likely a bad controller.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf of-course! You are correct. I read this wrong and thought he was connecting his PS4 controller to a PC :(

Comment: The *only* thing I might be able to suggest, is once to reset the controller, hold the right analog stick up. Then, once it connects, let go of the stick. It's possible that (somehow) the input from the controller is saying that the stick is being pushed up, when it actually isn't, so holding it in that position (should) calibrate it correctly.